# Chat-Bot sentence parsing methods

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp, string-matching

I have created a WhatsApp chat-bot using 'Selenium' and 'BeautifulSoup' in *Python*. I parse the incoming messages using Regex by matching it with pre defined data-sets.

However, I feel the parsing is mundane and lacks natural sense. The same match keeps happening again and again and hence the same message will be sent each time. I tried to solve this issue by using array of strings for the same match and sending it randomly each time.

I have heard of NLTK and its Natural Language Processing. Can I use that instead of Regex to make the chat-bot feel more natural? I have no clue of other string parsing methods. Which method would best suit my needs? Any suggestion would help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the regexes you are using and how you're using it?

Comment: For example : `regex_request  = [ "(?i)hi.*","(?i)hello.*"]` and `regex_response =[["hi","hi, how are you?"],["hello","hello..sup there?"]]`. For each match in `regex_request`, corresponding item in `regex_response` will be sent randomly. Using re.search to match the string.

Comment: Try picking regex at _random_. Keep a hash (or list) of regex indexes already tried. Keep everything else the same.

Comment: Yeah that would solve the problem a little because after each item in an array of stings is used up, it keeps repeating again. Is this the best I can do or should I try other methods like NLP?

Comment: I think NLP would be a big project. When you figure it all out, you may not get any better result. To be clear, right now you loop through the regex_request array 0..N is that right? And the regexes blindly find each one, not based on if they occurred in the string first, but based on which regex was used first. You could use a _single_ regex with alternations of phrases ( use [this tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg) ), which would match from left to right as found in the sentence. Then use a hash to get the response array. I can make it, need a link to the list.

Comment: Yeah, the reply that comes from a person is matched using regexes in `regex_request` and the string in `regex_response` will be chosen randomly. Here both `regex_response and regex_request` are mapped.

Comment: I don't get it ..How does the tool work?

Comment: On the left _input_ side, put in a list of ordinary literal words or phrases (default separator is newline), then pick the input and post-processing options. Pick your output options, then click the _Generate_ button. On the right-top side is the compressed regex, on the right-bottom side is the formatted (expanded) regex if the format check box is checked. The input for your sample would be `"hi\nhello"` and would produce the regex `(?i)(?:h(?:ello|i))` if you picked `_case insensitive_` and `_non-capture grouping_`

Comment: Here is an example of a multi-level trie it produces [175,000 word dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt). It basically makes a regex _trie_ of each node level in a ternary tree. Using this is only restricted by the source size allowed by regex engines. Most allow up to 1 MB. You would _pre-compile_ the regex when your program starts, then use it when needed. The speed is phenominal  because it never takes more than 5 steps to find any word. If you link to your list of words, I could generate for you.

Comment: Another thing that might work is to assign _weight_  to each output string that designates a position _level_. I.e. 1 level as priority over another. Then when you have all the strings in an array and another array for each weight, you could sort the weight array (and therefore the string array), then join the strings after the sort.. I guess in C++ it would simply be a array of structure{ string txt; int weight; }.